# How to make a billing/shipping state field mandatory when creating order from magento admin

Tags: module, magento-1, attributes

When i try creating order from magento admin, I want to make the state filed mandatory for shipping/billing address

I went to the sales module and found out that the fields are coming from the customer address model.

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Create\Form\Address.php 
protected function _prepareForm()

I can see $addressModel = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
```

I checked the customer module for the fields but was unable to find it out. 
Can i do it using customer module XML config files? OR any php code is required OR should i run a direct query in the database to make `required = 1`

Comment: Where/what should explain more?

Comment: I think by default it's in mandatory condition. now I checked

Comment: Its not mandatory.I use mage 1.5 *

Comment: do you want to make it mandatory for admin only? altering database will do it for both front and backend

Comment: @MTM: For both. Admin and frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this query in your database, you get expected result in all pages

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 1 WHERE attribute_code = 'region'
```